# Why is the soft clip domain code not working properly when filling the area between two curves?

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

Why the soft clip domain code doesn't work to fill 0 to 3?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{ decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=9, ymin=-1, ymax=4.5,
            ticks=none,
            xtick distance=0.5,
            ytick distance=0.5,
            axis equal image=true,
            grid,
            grid style={ultra thin, gray!10},
            grid=both,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
            ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south}
            ]
            \addplot[name path = A, red, thick, smooth] plot coordinates
            {   (0, 1)
                (1.5, 2.4)
                (3, 0.7)
                (4.3, 2.8)
                (5.4, 3)
                (6.5, 2)
                (7.5, 1)   };
        \addplot[name path = B, blue, thick, smooth] plot coordinates
        {    (0, 2)
            (1.5, 0.8)
            (3, 2.5)
            (5, 0.8)
            (6, 1.3)
            (6.7, 2)
            (7.5, 3)    };
    \addplot [fill=teal!40, opacity=0.5] fill between [of = A and B, soft clip={domain=0:3}];
    \draw (axis cs:7.5,0)--(axis cs:7.5,4);
    \node at (axis cs:7.5,-0.3) {\tiny 1};
    \node at (axis cs:0.2,-0.3) {\tiny 0};
    \node at (axis cs:5,3.5) {\tiny \color{red}$ y=f(x) $};
    \node at (axis cs:5,0.5) {\tiny \color{blue}$ y=g(x) $};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know why but tested `soft clip={domain=-0.1:3}` with worked for me. I don't write as answer because I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer but a MWE for bug report, -if it does not already exist**

This happens both inside `axis` with `\addplot` and inside `tikzpicture` with `\draw` but for different values dependent on the axis scale. It happens only when using the `smooth` option. It happens only when the `soft clip path` boundary coincides with the path start/end point.

-so it is always easily avoidable by extending the clip.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2, xmax=3,
ymin=-1, ymax=3,
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,-0.9,...,1}{
\addplot[
smooth,
postaction={decorate, draw, ultra thick, red},
decoration={soft clip, soft clip path={domain=#1:1}},
] plot coordinates{(#1,0) (2,2)};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with several lines that has different red thick parts]